# NOT CONTAINS in OrientDb EmbededSet

Tags: orientdb, orientdb-2.1

Trying to retrieve only orders not payed for an e-commerce website.

```
SELECT * FROM orders_list
WHERE status CONTAINS (type IN ['payed'])
AND status *not* CONTAINS (type IN ['payed'])
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM orders_list
WHERE status CONTAINS (type IN ['payed'])
AND status CONTAINS (type *not* IN ['payed'])
```

How I can do this query?

Thanks

Comment: Status is an EMBEDDEDSET like

[{type: 'payed', date : 1234567}, {type: 'refunded', date : 1324567 } ]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
SELECT * FROM orders_list
WHERE status CONTAINSALL (type NOT IN ['payed'])
```

Hope it helps.

**UPDATE**

I tried with this structure

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM orders_list
WHERE 'payed' NOT IN status
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM orders_list
WHERE status <> 'payed'
```

Let me know

Hope it helps